# How to ask turtles on specific patch to do something

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to get turtles on a specific, random patch to do something.
For example, I want to set a single random patch to be the color blue. I then want turtles that end up passing through that same random blue patch to die. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly it will be something like this:

First randomly set a patch blue:

```
let randomPatch one-of patches
ask randomPatch [ set pcolor blue]
```

And then:

```
let patch-under-me patch-here
if [pcolor] of patch-under-me = blue[
    die
]
```

This will need to go inside a function that is being called by a turtle, such as a move function.

Comment: Nice. You can also simplify to having `if pcolor = blue [ die ]` within the turtle's `ask` procedure, since the turtle will automatically understand a `pcolor` query to mean "the pcolor of the patch under me"